# Vuetify Slide Groups @click="toggle"

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

From the last example on this page: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/slide-groups

I'm trying to understand how the following actually works:

```html
<v-slide-item 
  v-for="n in 15" 
  :key="n" 
  v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }">

  <v-card 
    :color="active ? 'primary' : 'grey lighten-1'"
    class="ma-4" 
    height="200" 
    width="100" 
    @click="toggle"
  >
```

The v-card component has a `@click=toggle` on it, which somehow affects its parent component with `v-slot`? Is toggle a special keyword here?

In other words, does `@click="toggle"` make "active" true or false?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is toggle a special keyword here?

Yes, it's a native function as it is inside of your `v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }`.

> In other words, does @click="toggle" make "active" `true or false`?

Yes, when you click to `<v-card>` this `toggle` function will make the `active` to `true/false` by with the help of [`model`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels#v-model-control).

The following line declares a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) default variable and it is provided a scope object, which contains `active, toggle`

```
v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }"
```

---

We can also create our custom click as well for the `v-card` and inside of that click we can change `model` value. Like below

```
<v-card
    :color="active ? 'primary' : 'grey lighten-1'"
    class="ma-4"
    height="100"
    width="100"
    @click="onCardClick(n)"
>
//Custom click event
methods:{
    onCardClick(n){
      this.model = n - 1;
    }
}
```

I have created [codepen](https://codepen.io/narendrajadhav/pen/zYOQLbj) demo, this will more guide you to understand the logic of `toggle` and `model`.